# Iterating over vectors in C++ and erasing certain elements

Tags: c++

Just to provide background, I'm trying to write a function in C++ that takes a vector of ints and a particular int, and removes all of the elements of the vector in place that match the particular int, while returning the number of times it appears.

I'm not asking for help solving the problem. I am stuck trying to figure out why the wrong elements are being erased. Here is the code:

```
int removeElement(vector<int>& nums, int val) {
    int output = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < nums.size()) {
        cout << nums[i] << "  " << i << "  " << (nums[i] == val) << "\n";
        if (nums[i] == val) {
            nums.erase(nums.begin() + i);
            output+=1;
        }
        else {
            i += 1;
        }
    }
    cout << "---------------\n";
    return output;
    }
```

Here is what I'm using to test it:

```
int main() {
    vector<int> firstOne = {3,2,2,3};
    cout << removeElement(firstOne,2) << "\n";
    firstOne = {3,2,2,3};
    cout << removeElement(firstOne,3) << "\n";
}
```

The output is supposed to be {3,3} and then {2,2} but it's {3,3} twice. Not only that, but the whole thing crashes when I try to test it with a vector with only 2 elements. I suspect there is a gap in my understanding of how vectors work. Can anyone explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Both your `removeElement` calls pass `2` as the second parameter. Did you mean to pass `3` in the second call? Also, this can't be the exact code that you're running, since you've declared `firstOne` twice in the same scope. Please make sure your code is *reproducible*.

Comment: Sorry folks, fixed now.

Comment: Also, where are you updating `output`?

Comment: @AidanQuinn Your latest code works for me. I added this `for (int n : firstOne) cout << n << ' '; cout << '\n';` after both calls to `removeElement` and the correct values get printed. It also works correctly with a vector of two elements. So whatever problem you are having it's not in the code you have posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the problems suggested in the comments that you just fixed, your code works fine. You are also not updating `output` anywhere so the function always returns `0` instead of the number of times the `int` appears in the passed `vector`. I edited your function a little and it's good to go:

```
int removeElement(vector<int>& nums, int val) {
    int output = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < nums.size()) {
        cout << nums[i] << "  " << i << "  " << (nums[i] == val) << "\n";
        if (nums[i] == val) {
            nums.erase(nums.begin() + i);
            output++;
        }
        else {
            i += 1;
        }
    }
    cout << "---------------\n";
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom)

```
int removeElement(vector<int>& nums, int val) {
    int output = 0;
    int i = 0;
    // remove if moves elements "to be removed" in the end
    auto newend = std::remove_if(nums.begin(), nums.end(), [&](int element){
        cout << element << "  " << i << "  " << (element == val) << "\n";
        
        i++;
        if(element == val) {
            output++;
            return true; // if true, element will be removed
        }

        return false; // if false, element will not be removed
    });

    nums.erase(newend, nums.end());

    cout << "---------------\n";
    return output;
}
```